# C++ vector not printing correct value after dereference?

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

Hi my code is very simple and below:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <tuple>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

tuple<int, float, string, vector<int>&> foo() {
    vector<int> L = {1,2,3};
    cout << L[0] << L[1] << L[2] << endl;
    return {1, 1.2, "asdf", L};

}

int main()
{
    
    auto [a, b, c, d] = foo();
    cout << "read: " << d[0] << d[1] << d[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I read inside the foo function I get 123 as expected.
However, when I read in main I get: -17648164883276715. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
The reason why I'm sending a pointer is because I don't want the function to copy the vector again and make it more efficient.

Comment: You don't pass a pointer but a reference. And it's dangling, thus you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: @abdullaDev Just remove the `&` in `vector<int>`.

If you are using C++11 or newer, recommendation is to pass containers to functions by reference but return them by value. The vector will not be copied back, just moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `L` is a local variable and stored in stack memory which is within the scope of `foo()` function. At the end of `foo()` function, the scope of the function is cleaned up (ie. stack memory is cleaned up as well).

You should create your vector in heap memory in order to achieve what you want:

```
tuple<int, float, string, vector<int>*> foo() {
    vector<int> *L = new vector<int>({1,2,3});
    cout << L->at(0) << L->at(1) << L->at(2) << endl;
    return {1, 1.2, "asdf", L};

}

int main()
{    
    auto [a, b, c, d] = foo();
    cout << "read: " << d->at(0) << d->at(1) << d->at(2) << endl;
    delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should then clean the memory up manually with `delete d`. In general, you should avoid doing things like that because it is easy to miss the clean up logic.

Answer (score 1):

You return a reference to a local variable that is destroyed when going out of scope. Long story short, the vector reference is dangling.